# How can I convert a string to an integer within Bash?

Tags: bash, fedora

I am attempting to create a cronjob that will run depending on the output of disk usage for a specific folder. In my test environment, I have a folder called "Test" that is 4.0 Kilobytes. I am querying its size with:

```
du -csh /home/<username>/Test | grep total | cut -f1 | tr -d 'K'
```

The output is assigned to a variable called DISK_SPACE and leaves me with `4.0`. I cannot figure out how to convert 4.0 to an integer in order to satisfy the following:

```
if [ $DISK_SPACE -gt 3.0 ]
then
rm -rf /home/<username>/Test/*.*
else
echo $DISK_SPACE "is less than 3.0K and as a result the contents of the folder will NOT be deleted."
```

My full bash file looks like the below:

```
#!/bin/bash
DISK_SPACE=$(du -csh /home/<username>/Test | grep total | cut -f1 | tr -d 'K')
echo $DISK_SPACE
if [ $DISK_SPACE -gt 3.0 ]
then
rm -rf /home/<username>Test/*.*
else
echo $DISK_SPACE "is less than 3.0K and as a result the contents of the folder will NOT be deleted."
fi
```

The error I receive after running this is:

```
4.0: integer expression expected
```

Comment: Your title suggests a more general question than just one involving disk utilization computation and comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`du -h` prints numbers for human consumption. A script shouldn't use `-h`. Try `-k` or `-b` instead to get easy-to-parse integers:

```
-k     like --block-size=1K

-b, --bytes
       equivalent to '--apparent-size --block-size=1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `printf` to round your real number to an integer.

```
printf "%1.0f\n" 4.0
4

printf "%1.0f\n" 4.6
5
```

See the [printf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) manpages.

For you example you can do:

```
DISK_SPACE=4.0
DISK_SPACE=$(printf "%1.0f" ${DISK_SPACE})
echo ${DISK_SPACE}
4
```

Comment: Under [tag:bash] use  `printf -v DISK_SPACE %.0f $DISKSPACE`. This will avoid one fork and use builtin `printf -v` to set variable.

Answer (score 0):

Bash has no support for floating point arithmetic. If you just care whether the first digit is bigger than 3, you can simply trim any decimals.

```
if [ "${disk_space%.*}" -gt 3 ]; then ...
```

If you need proper float comparison, perhaps it's simpler to actually [use a tool which supports floating-point arithmetic.](/questions/8654051/how-to-compare-two-floating-point-numbers-in-bash)

Notice also that I converted your variable to lower case. You [should not use all-uppercase names for your private variables.](/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Comment: Your second example is missing a closing `"` on the variable expansion. And it's also broken in that it dies with an error for `disk_space=3.0`.

Comment: Thanks, removed that portion, which was kind of silly anyway.

Comment: Yeah, it was probably overkill. But it actually would have worked if you'd replaced the `-eq` with `=` (i.e., just doing regular string comparison instead of a numeric "equals" test). In that case, things like `"3.0000"`, etc would just stay as they were and therefore fail the string comparison as intended, while things like `"3.00195"` would be chopped down to `"3"`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to John Kugelman's answer I also changed the following line:

Original:

```
if [ $DISK_SPACE -gt 3.0 ]
```

New:

```
if [ $DISK_SPACE -gt 3072 ]
```

This allowed John's recommended change to work even better with the script:

```
du -csb /home/<username>/Test | grep total | cut -f1
```